# Dúvida Exercício Python

Tags: python

O desafio é: Escreva um programa que recebe como entradas (utilize a função input) dois números inteiros correspondentes à largura e à altura de um retângulo, respectivamente. O programa deve imprimir uma cadeia de caracteres que represente o retângulo informado com caracteres '#' na saída. O meu programa, quando digito 2 e 2 pra altura e largura.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
l=int(input("Digite a largura: "))
a=int(input("Digite a altura: "))

linha=0
coluna=0

while linha<a:
    while coluna<l:
        print("#", end=" ")
        coluna=coluna+1
    print()    
    linha=linha+1
    coluna=1
```

Comment: Coloque coluna = 0 no final do código. Com coluna = 1 você começa como se já tivesse sido colocado um '#'.

Answer (score 4):

O principal problema é que você está reinicializando o valor da coluna em 1 dentro do loop:

```
coluna=1
```

Troque para que a coluna seja reinicializada no valor 0 e sua impressão do retângulo já ficará correta:

```
coluna = 0
```

O código completo ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
l = int(input("Digite a largura: "))
a = int(input("Digite a altura: "))

linha = 0
coluna = 0

while linha < a:
    while coluna < l:
        print("#", end=" ")
        coluna = coluna + 1
    print()

    linha = linha+1
    coluna = 0
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/OfficialAngryLibrary

---

Uma opção é utilizar o laço `for` para resolver esse exercício de forma bem simples:

```
l = int(input("Digite a largura: "))
a = int(input("Digite a altura: "))

for _ in range(a):
  print("# " * l)
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/DarkgreyLimpingBoolean

Answer (score 4):

Opa, mano, o erro que acontece é que você está reiniciando o primeiro While com a coluna igual a 1, e por ele já começar com 1 a mais, se você colocar 4, por exemplo, ele só vai inserir os 3 "#" posteriores.

```
l=int(input("Digite a largura: "))
a=int(input("Digite a altura: "))

linha=0
coluna=0

while linha<a:
    while coluna<l:
        print("#", end=" ")
        coluna=coluna+1
    print()    
    linha=linha+1
    coluna= 0 #Esse aqui foi o erro, você havia colocado "coluna= 1"
```

Você precisa reiniciar a coluna com ela recebendo 0, e isso já resolveria seus problemas.

Answer (score 2):

O problema do seu código é que você atribui na última linha o valor 1 para a variável `coluna`. Dessa forma, o seu programa irá imprimir um caractere `"#"` a menos.

Para corrigir o problema, basta trocar o valor 1 para zero.

```
coluna = 0
```

---

Você também pode melhorar o seu código de algumas formas. Veja abaixo algumas dicas:

- Utilize o operador `+=` para incrementar um valor sem precisar repetir a variável.

  ```
  coluna = coluna + 1     
  coluna += 1         # É equivalente a linha de cima.
  ```
- No seu caso, é muito melhor utilizar um laço `for` já que reduz algumas linhas e deixa o código mais bonito.

  ```
  for lin in range(altura):
      for col in range(largura):
          print("#", end = "")
      print()
  ```
- Não é necessário utilizar um laço de repetição para a largura. Basta utilizar o operador `*` para repetir uma string.

  ```
  for lin in range(altura):
      print("#" * largura)
  ```

Veja o código abaixo e perceba o quão simples pode ficar seu programa:

```
largura = int(input("Digite a largura: "))
altura = int(input("Digite a altura: "))

for linha in range(altura):
    print("#" * largura)
```

Answer (score 2):

Vendo a imagem, não ficou claro se deve ou não ter um espaço entre os `#`. No seu código você colocou, mas de qualquer forma, segue uma alternativa para ambos os casos (não vou sugerir os *loops* novamente porque isso já foi bem abordado nas demais respostas, é só para deixar registrado outra alternativa).

---

Em Python é possível "multiplicar" uma string por um número, então `'#' * 2` produz a string `'##'`. Sendo assim, para cada linha bastaria fazer `('#' * largura) + '\n'` (o `#` vezes a largura para produzir vários `#`, e o `\n` para a quebra de linha. Depois, basta multiplicar isso pela altura para termos várias linhas:

```
largura = int(input("Digite a largura: "))
altura = int(input("Digite a altura: "))

print((('#' * largura) + '\n') * altura)
```

Também mudei os nomes das variáveis para algo mais significativo. Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad), então crie este hábito desde já.

Se quiser os espaços, basta mudar para `'# ' * largura`. Lembrando que isso vai colocar um espaço "extra" no final da linha. Além disso, esta solução (e algumas das sugestões nas outras respostas também) colocam uma linha em branco a mais no final. Você pode evitar isso criando listas e juntando-as com `join`:

```
# cria uma linha do retângulo, com os # separados por espaços (sem o espaço extra no final)
linha = ' '.join(['#'] * largura)
# cria várias linhas separadas por \n, sem a linha extra no final
print('\n'.join([linha] * altura))
```

Answer (score -1):

no formato abaixo acredito que atende sua necessidade.

```
l = int(input('digite a largura: '))
a = int(input('digite a altura: '))

while  a > 0:
   aux = 0
   while aux < l:
     print('#',end="")
     aux+=1  
   a-=1
   print()
```

Answer (score -2):

saiu desconfigurado, primeira vez que envio rsrs

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Remova esta resposta, a sua outra resposta já está formatada nos padrões do StackOverflow.